# is there a way to add new value at beginning of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this python dictionary

```
my_dic = {
     0:{"food":"banana"},
     1:{"food":"apple"},
     2:{"food":"orange"}
}
```

and I want When never I added new value to ***my_dic***  I wanted  it to be in the to beginning of  ***my_dic*** with key 0 so ***my_dic*** looks like that

```
my_dic = {
     0:{new value},
     1:{"food":"banana"},
     2:{"food":"apple"},
     3:{"food":"orange"}
}
```

Comment: Better use queue

Comment: If you need that kind of ordering, you need a `list`, not a `dict`.  Any time you see a `dict` with sequentially numbered keys, the wrong data structure has been chosen.

Comment: Do you need to access the dictionaries by index?

Comment: as much as i want to use list , the data i have to insert it has to be as dictionary

Comment: @urekmazino no, it doesn't.

Comment: But what do you want to do with the data? Are planning to access it by index or what? I ask because you could use an ordereddict

Comment: You should probably just use a `collections.deque` and use `.appendleft`

Comment: @DaniMesejo just a regular `dict` will do, almost certainly. But really, the OP should use a `collections.deque`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga was about to suggest just that. :-)

Comment: An OrderedDict has a method move_to_end, that basically puts a key at the beginning

Comment: @DaniMesejo ah yes, but it won't automatically shift all the keys up by `+1`.

Comment: Hence my question

Comment: Create two dictionaries. One dictionary uses numeric keys for indexing you want, the value for those keys would be the key of your primary dictionary. You could also create a new class around this principle, with functions that provide exactly what you want. As others have pointed out, you're not really going to get what you have described. The new class option would be how I would go about it, so I'm not constantly dealing with two dictionaries. The object would be managed by your new functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it

```
my_dic = {
     0:{"food":"banana"},
     1:{"food":"apple"},
     2:{"food":"orange"}
   }

my_dic = {0: "New value", **{k+1: v for k, v in my_dic.items()}}
```

which basically creates a new dict and puts the old one at the end.

This returns

```
{0: 'New value', 1: {'food': 'banana'}, 2: {'food': 'apple'}, 3: {'food': 'orange'}}
```

Since this is not performant, you should check, if you can do with another data structure. Many commenters suggested using a `collections.deque()` and that's what I would chose myself as well.

Comment: it's perfectly working , I'm getting the result I want thanks

Comment: @urek But as the commenters have been at pains to explain, there is no good reason for you to want that result,  because that indicates a fundamental  misunderstanding of what a dict is for.

Comment: @BoarGules unfortunately that what i really need , i'm making crawler for wordpress site if i do not make the dict in this format then serialize it using phpserialize and insert it in database crawled posts will not appear in home page , also theme is decrypted using ioncube so i could not understand how it work